# Python cannot run module from command line; IPython can

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the directory structure for my modules:
[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8cPW.png)

As can be seen, `DataProcessor` is a module inside which `DataLoader` has certain functions.

Inside the `lda` module, the file `HFT.py` have the line 
from DataProcessor import DataLoader

I am trying to run `lda/HFT.py` from the main directory `274-Yelp/`

`python lda/HFT.py`
this gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lda/HFT.py", line 6, in <module>
    from DataProcessor import DataLoader
ImportError: No module named DataProcessor
```

However, when I run
`ipython lda/HFT.py`
it runs!

I am using a virtualenv located in the main directory `274-Yelp/`

Can someone tell me why Ipython can import the module but normal Python interpreter can't?

Contents of `DataProcessor/__init__.py`:

```
import DataLoader
import MatrixConstructor
import ReviewProcessor
import vocabBuilder
```

Contents of `lda/__init__.py`:

from ReviewModel im

```
port ReviewModel
from RatingModel import RatingModel
from HFT import HFT
```

Comment: if you do a which python and a which ipython what are the results?

Comment: Can you specify the content of `init.py` in `DataProcessor` module and `lda` module

Comment: Try adding `sys.path.append(absolute path of DataProcessor module )` in `lda/HFT.py` file on the top before ` from DataProcessor import DataLoader` statement.

Comment: `which python`: .../274B-Yelp/yelp_env/bin/python    


`which ipython`: .../274B-Yelp/yelp_env/bin/ipython

Comment: @Tanu - I have included the contents in the question. Adding `sys.path` should work, but even if it does, why is there a difference between how iPython interprets my file and how Python does it?

Answer (score 0):

The path calculation for your python scripts is being affected by initializers or cd directory, or your ipython is actually launching a different python binary. Given that your ipython is pointing into your virtualenv directory I am guessing its the former.

Normally the directory you're running from is added to the `sys.path` for you benefit, but it looks like you might be running this from Eclipse given the screenshot. That has its own current directory settings for each run that you can configure under run settings.

You might have added the working directory into your .ipython file (found via `ipython locate`) which would only help ipython runs.

To fix the issue either add the path to your project root directory to the top of both init files as a `sys.path.insert(1, 'my/root/path')`, or combine the separate modules into a single module with relative importing `from ..DataProcessor import DataLoader`. This required that the shared parent directory have an `__init__.py` file but allows run something like `python -m shareddir.lda.HFT` to always know about the relative path to other modules.